# Does my validation curve indicate over fitting from train and test?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, overfitting, boosting

I carried out a grid search on my xgboost and varied the parameters below. I noticed in my grid search results that the train score is very high, e.g. 0.99999 and my test scores are more modest around 0.72. Since there is such a big difference between my train and test score does this indicate over fitting?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume your score is a metric like accuracy, f1-score etc. If that is the case, yes, it quite certainly indicates *overfitting*. 28% accuracy difference between train and test/validation is very high, and it means the model didn't generalise as well for the test set as the training set.

Comment: what if i am also doing a grid search on say brier score, how can i tell over fitting?

Comment: It still is large. It's also interesting to see that your scores don't change wrt hyperparameter changes